# [CMD]Как скопировать первые n строк

Tags: cmd

Как скопировать первые n строк из файла source.txt в файл 1.txt
Желательно наиболее короткое решение.

Comment: Да циклом. А унутре `set /A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=0
set inputFile=source.txt
set outputFile=1.txt
set maxLines=3
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%inputFile%) do (
    set /a count=!count!+1
    echo %%a >> %outputFile%
    if !count! == %maxLines% goto :EOF
)
```